# Web scraping Google's Hotel Finder

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm trying to teach myself how to web scrape hotel data.

```
    <?php

$url = "https://www.google.com/hotels/#search;l=Denpasar-Bali+Ngurah+Rai,+Denpasar,+ID;d=2015-04-30;n=6;usd=1;si=dc7b320c;av=r";
$curl_connection = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;



?>
```

I cannot get any hotel data from Google. So just wanted to ask for some help in scraping the hotel data.

Comment: Do you get any result? any error message?

Comment: try to print the result in var_dump($result) and check . do you get any result or error message ?

Comment: Quite a lot of Google's services rely on JavaScript. This may be for the purposes of making scraping harder to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is special. You try to scrape google's hotels directory.

1. Be aware that google is limiting requesting search pages (incl. paginaton) to certain limit to protect data from web scraping. The request frequency is also under control: proving if it's human or bot doing multiple requests.
2. Seems you have GET parameters, so please check how to form them in query with CUrl.
3. Since you try to query google's hotels (business) directory (https://www.google.com/hotels/#search), be aware of scraping such directories, see [some tips](https://webscraping.pro/business-directories-scrape-tips-tricks/).